# laravel file uploading to folder and database

Tags: php

I can'nt upload image to public/images folder and also i can't save image name to my database. **Undefined variable: imageName** this error was generated

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
      $adm_companies=new adm_companies;

      $adm_companies->com_name=$request->cname;

      $adm_companies->com_company_address=$request->caddress;

      $adm_companies->com_country=$request->country;

      //$imageName="";

      if($request->hasFile('filename'))

      {

      $imageName = time().'.'.request()->

           filename->getClientOriginalExtension();

      request()->filename->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

      }

      $adm_companies->com_logo=$imageName;

      $adm_companies->com_phone1=$request->cphone1;

      $adm_companies->com_phone2=$request->cphone2;

      $adm_companies->com_fax=$request->fax;

      $adm_companies->com_email=$request->emailid;

      if($adm_companies->save())

      {

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>

        alert('Inserted successfully!', window.history.back())

        </script>"; 

      }

      else

      {

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>

        alert('Insertion failed!',window.history.back()) 

        </script>";

      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If no file uploaded this error should appear.

Check if you have added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form.

Also do

```
  $imageName="";
  if($request->hasFile('filename'))
  {
       $imageName = time().'.'.request()->
                    filename->getClientOriginalExtension();
       request()->filename->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
  }
```

So that if no file uploaded it would store blank to that variable.

And if the file field is compulsory the I would suggest to add proper validations.